# Groupby complex function

Tags: python

I have an iterator containing strings:

```
it = (_ for _ in ['aaxbb', 'aayybb', 'aaaaaaabb', 'ccabcavabb', 'yyaaadbb', 'yyaabb', 'a'])
```

I want to group these string if they have the same first and last two characters. The end result of the groupby in the above example should be:

```
[['aaxbb', 'aayybb', 'aaaaaaabb'],
 ['ccabcavabb'],
 ['yyaaadbb', 'yyaabb'],
 ['a']]
```

Can this complex groupby be achieved using `itertools.groupby`?

Comment: `iter(listobj)` is a shorter way of saying `(_ for _ in listobj)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not complex at all, just return a tuple of the first and last two characters:

```
lambda v: (v[:2], v[-2:])
```

or, if you want to use `operator.itemgetter()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

itemgetter(slice(2), slice(-2, None))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sample = ['aaxbb', 'aayybb', 'aaaaaaabb', 'ccabcavabb', 'yyaaadbb', 'yyaabb', 'a']
>>> for key, group in groupby(sample, lambda v: (v[:2], v[-2:])):
...     print list(group)
... 
['aaxbb', 'aayybb', 'aaaaaaabb']
['ccabcavabb']
['yyaaadbb', 'yyaabb']
['a']
>>> for key, group in groupby(sample, itemgetter(slice(2), slice(-2, None))):
...     print list(group)
... 
['aaxbb', 'aayybb', 'aaaaaaabb']
['ccabcavabb']
['yyaaadbb', 'yyaabb']
['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to do sorting first before using groupby. In this specific example, all the items that belong to a group appear consecutively, so sorting might be optional. But in general, the collection must be sorted before using groupby.

See the note from Python documentation regarding the same
https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

"The operation of groupby() is similar to the uniq filter in Unix. It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes (which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted the data using the same key function). That behavior differs from SQL’s GROUP BY which aggregates common elements regardless of their input order."

```
sample = ['aaxbb', 'aayybb', 'aaaaaaabb', 'ccabcavabb', 'yyaaadbb', 'yyaabb', 'a', 'aaxxbb']
print [list(group) for key, group in groupby(sorted(sample), lambda x: x[:2]+x[-2:])]
```